# How can I fix my pyCharm installation?

Tags: windows, pycharm

When I start pyCharm I get this error msg:

```
Load Settings
Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\cleanup\.PyCharm40\config\options\editor.codeinsight.xml': content truncated File content will be recreated
```

What can I do about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the file is empty.

1. Go to File -> Settings -> Editor -> General, and
   review the settings (under 'Smart keys', 'Appearance', and the other sub-menus).
2. The file will be re-populated with any changes you made.

If you are OK with using configuration defaults for the editor, just delete the file to get rid of the error message.

Comment: The source code is available on GitHub, so you can actually see where the error comes from and what is stored in the file.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But it didn't work. I still get the error even though I followed the instructions.

Comment: Did you try to delete the file? Keep a backup just in case, although I believe it's empty.

Comment: Yes I tried deleting the file. It did not work. I still get the error message. The file was empty when I deleted it.

Comment: That's weird. What version of PyCharm are you using? Is it Community or Professional Edition? I was able to reproduce your problem and tested the solution before posting the answer. With PyCharm 4.0.x and 4.5 Community Edition.

Comment: I use PyCharm 4.5 Professional Edition and after restarting several times, the problem now doesn't appear anymore. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: Oh, sure, you're welcome! I wonder what caused this. IntelliJ is a very reliable platform.